# MaaS Enlistment through 12.10 installation CD fails (SIGKILL problem)

Tags: maas

I have deployed the latest 12.10 Ubuntu Server MAAS installation from the CD ISO distribution.
I have run on the installed node the following commands:

```
sudo maas createsuperuser
sudo maas-import-pxe-files
sudo apt-get install maas-enlist
sudo apt-get install tftpd-hpa
sudo maas-import-isos -u
```

When I boot another machine on the same network from CD to Install with MAAS after I choose the MAAS server I get the following error on screen:

> Sent SIGKILL to all processes Requesting system poweroff

The machine shuts down then.

This error happens with physical hardware and also with a virtual setup in cloud.

I have read all the recommendations in another threads on this topic but nothing helps.
Could anyone give me a support for this issue?

Comment: When I enter the ip address of the MAAS server manually the failure is the same but in the web interface of MAAS I can observe the node registered with status "Declared".

Answer (score 2):

Once a node has enlisted it is shut down and the status will be "Declared" in the MAAS web interface. The next step is to edit the node settings then click "Accept and Commission".

After clicking "Accept and Commission" your machine will power on automatically if you configured IPMI. If not, you will need to power the machine on again and it will show as "Commissioning". Once the node is commissioned it will power down again and show as "Ready"

When you deploy a service with juju the machine status will become "Allocated to ". Power on the machine again for the service to deploy.